# Show only the last plot in Python using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using Python 3.5 with MatPlotLib package. My problem is as follows:
I generate, say 50 plots, which I save each to a PNG file. Then I generate 2 summarizing plots, which I want to both save and show on display. However, when I use the `plt.show()` command, it also shows all the previous 50 plots, which I don't want to display, just save them. How to suppress the show on these previous 50 plots and show only the last one?

Here is an example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(50):
   fig = plt.figure()
   plt.plot(np.arange(10),np.arange(10)) # just plot something
   plt.savefig(f"plot_{i}.png")
   # I want to save these plots but not show them
# summarizing plot
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(100),np.arange(100))
plt.show() # now it shows this fig and the previous 50 figs, but I want only to show this one!
```

Comment: You need `plt.clf()` to clear the previous figures before plotting the final figures

Comment: `plt.clf() ` just clears the last (current) figure, so that when you `plt.show()` you'll get 49 figures with a drawing, tha last one cleared and the summary figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close all after the loop:

```
plt.close("all") #this is the line to be added
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(100),np.arange(100))
plt.show()
```